# get previous page "pagecontainer transition"

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Is it possible to get the page I'm coming from when using jQuery Mobile's "pagecontainertransition"?

```
$('body').on('pagecontainertransition', function(event, ui) {
    //previous page
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could use

```
$('body').on('pagecontainertransition', function(event, ui) {
    //previous page id
    ui.options.fromPage.attr('id')
});
```

Comment: if you want jquery page object then use  **ui.options.fromPage**

Comment: Great one. Ill stick this in my notes

Comment: easier - `ui.prevPage`.

Comment: Hi @Omar , I am getting **undefined** from **ui.prevPage** in **pagecontainertransition** event

Comment: _first_ page will definitely return `undefined`. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/9vd5prfL/

Comment: ui.options.fromPage.attr('id') returns undefined
ui.options.fromPage and ui.prevPage both return and object.

Comment: @OpoloWebdesign which version of jQM are you using?